# RecyclerView is not showing results

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView is not showing items. My RecyclerView is defined in next class. In debug mode I can see that is calling the Adapter but I don't know how to see if the Adapter is correctly showing items. So I share with you the Adapter.

```
do {
    Integer id = cursor.getInt(0);
    String nome = cursor.getString(1);
    String receita = cursor.getString(2);
    //builder.append(id + nome + receita);

    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPesquisa);
    mTitulo.add(nome);
    mTexto.add(receita);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mTitulo, mTexto);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

As requested, please see in below the Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG ="RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> mTextViewItem = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mTextViewText;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mTextViewItem, ArrayList<String> mTextViewText) {
        mTextViewText = mTextViewItem;
        mTextViewText = mTextViewText;
        mContext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
        holder.textviewReceitaItem.setText(mTextViewItem.get(position));
        holder.textViewReceitaText.setText(mTextViewText.get(position));
        holder.lista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on:" + mTextViewItem.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, mTextViewText.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTextViewItem.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textviewReceitaItem;
        TextView textViewReceitaText;
        RelativeLayout lista;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textviewReceitaItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewReceitaItem);
            textViewReceitaText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReceitaText);
            lista = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue, You shouldn't create `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerViewAdapter` in every iteration

Comment: add codes to your `Adapter` and your `item_layout.xml`

Comment: Adapter provided